# Nested "for" in Django view won´t work

Tags: python, json, django, for-loop, nested

I want to generate a *JSON* type object for a *HttpResponse* and in order to build it i´m using a nested "for" structure. I wrote down some code, tried it with my python interpreter but when I used it on my django view it refuses to work correctly.

My structure is something like this:

```
tarifas = ['2.0A','2.0DHA','2.0DHSA']
terminos = ['Dia','Hora','GEN','NOC','VHC','COFGEN','COFNOC','COFVHC','PMHGEN','PMHNOC','PMHVHC','SAHGEN','SAHNOC','SAHVHC','FOMGEN','FOMNOC','FOMVHC','FOSGEN','FOSNOC','FOSVHC','INTGEN','INTNOC','INTVHC','PCAPGEN','PCAPNOC','PCAPVHC','TEUGEN','TEUNOC','TEUVHC']

data_json = {}
data_json['datos_TOT'] = []
data_json['datos_TEU'] = []
data_json['fecha'] = fecha

for i in range(3):
    data_json['datos_TOT'].append({})
    data_json['datos_TEU'].append({})
    data_json['datos_TOT'][i]['tarifa'] = tarifas[i]
    data_json['datos_TEU'][i]['tarifa'] = tarifas[i]


    for j in range(0,24):
        data_json['datos_TEU'][i]['values'] = []
        data_json['datos_TEU'][i]['values'].append({})
        data_json['datos_TEU'][i]['values'][j]['periodo'] = "{0}-{1}".format(j,j+1)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_json), content_type="application/json")
```

In fact it has one more depth level but as the second don´t work I didn´t put it here.

With this nested structure I expected a JSON object with (b-a) entries in the first level with (d-c) entries each one. But what I see is that the second loop only returns the last value! So if the "j" loop goes from 0 to 24 it will just return "23" and nothing more. Seems like it just works one "lap".

Is there any limit in nesting loops in the views? If there is, where could I place them? I´m trying to keep the models.py free from logic.

Comment: You are clearly doing something wrong. Provide us more of your code.

Comment: Even though nested for loops are okay in Python, Django doesn't allow too many indentation levels in views... just kidding! Please post more of your code because this is _not_ a problem with nested for loops in general. It's good that you try to keep logic out of your models though!

Comment: I´ve just added some more code. I kept the 3rd loop out until I know what´s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you reset `data_json['datos_TEU'][i]['values']` to an empty list at the beginning of every iteration of the `j` loop, so it will only ever have one element. Move that line to before the nested loop.

Note that your code could be written much more Pythonically:

```
for tarifa in tarifas:
    tot = {'tarifa': tarifa}
    data_json['datos_TOT'].append(tot)

    teu = {'tarifa': tarifa}
    values = []
    for j, termino in enumerate(terminos):
        value = {'termino': termino, 'periodo': "{0}-{1}".format(j,j+1)}
        values.append(value)
    teu['values'] = values
    data_json['datos_TEU'].append(teu)
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you!
I don´t master python so much as you so I will study your post to understand ow you did it hehe.